# git fetch not working - but checkout working

Tags: git, git-pull, git-checkout, git-fetch

I am beginner to git and trying some hands on with it on Windows.

I made a repository on Bitbucket. Added Three files ( SAY A , B , C ) to the master branch via Bitbucket online .

Now  i have folder on my local PC , where i used `git fetch` for getting those three file. Three files are now in local repository.

Now , i added one other file (SAY D )  on bitbucket , and changed the content of all three files (A , B , C ) .

Now if i try to fetch the changes via `git fetch MY_REMOTE master`  ,  I am not getting any changes in my local. but

- with `git pull MY_REMOTE master` , I am able to see the changes.
- with `git checkout MY_REMOTE/master` , I am able to see the changes.

  So the doubt i have ,
- `git fetch` simply copies the changes those are not on the local to the local repo except Local repo have changed the same copy. Why `git fetch` is not working here ?
- I don't understand the purpose of doing `git checkout MY_REMOTE/master` on Local . Why should i do that ?

Answer (score 4):

Git's `fetch` does not get files—well, not directly anyway.

To some extent, Git doesn't care that much about files at all.  What Git cares about are *commits*.  Before we visit this idea any further, though, we should probably review some basic Git definitions.

## What's in a repository

A *Git repository* has three main parts: *commits*, the *index*, and the *work-tree*.  (Some Git repositories will omit the work-tree, and in newer versions of Git you can have more than one work-tree, where each work-tree has its own index.  But in general you start with one of each.)

A *commit* is a snapshot: a complete *set* of files.  It's not just *a* file, and it's not the *difference* in some files either: it's a standalone thing, with all the files you have decided to save in that commit, in the form they had when you saved them.  A commit is also permanent and unchanging.  Like all Git objects, it has a unique identifier: `3313b78c145ba9212272b5318c111cde12bfef4a`, for instance.  Once it is stored, you can never change *anything* in a commit.  If you try, you get a *copy* of the commit, with the change, and the copy has a new, different ID.  You can (sometimes) *delete* a commit entirely, but you can't change it, only copy it—well, most of it, all but the changed part of course—to a new different-ID commit.

Git really, *really* cares about commits.  It works very hard to make sure you never lose one.  It cares much less about the index and work-tree: those are neither permanent, nor unchanging.  The advantages of commits are obvious, but their disadvantage is also obvious: they're stored inside Git—in the repository—in a form that nothing else on the computer can deal with.

The *work-tree* is the opposite of this: it's in a form that *everything* else on the computer can deal with, and it's quite impermanent and changeable.  It's where you do all your work.  It has files, rather than mysterious Git objects.  This is where you read, write, and edit your files.

Git's *index* is initially quite mysterious to most people (it was to me), and it has a lot of complicated twists you will eventually encounter.  Some software tries to hide the index entirely, but that's not a good idea.  In one way the index is actually very simple though:  It's where Git has you build the *next commit*.  The index starts out matching the *current* commit, and then you `git add` new versions of existing files, or entirely new files, to the index, to copy the new ones in.  Then when you run `git commit`, Git makes a new commit out of whatever you have in the index right now.  This makes the permanent, unchanging snapshot.  The index, which is also called the *staging area*, is simply where you arrange (or "stage") your files to make them as pretty as possible for the snapshot.

Each commit also records the ID of its immediate predecessor, or *parent*, commit.  This becomes crucial as soon as you start working with history.  The history is formed *by the commits themselves*, through this "my parent is ..." information.

A branch name like `master` simply identifies—by its ID—the *newest* commit on that branch.  Git calls this the *tip* of the branch.  This newest commit remembers its parent, and that parent remembers its own parent (the newest commit's grandparent), and so on.  Git also has other entities that do the same kind of thing: remember one specific commit's ID.  The most important two are *tags* and *remote-tracking branches*.

#### Summary

A repository contains *commits*, which contain *snapshots*, and which form the history of all commits ever made.  The *branch name* `master` finds the *newest* commit on `master`.  And, although commits *contain* files, they are not themselves files: they contain whole sets of files, all as one collection.

A repository has an index, which is an intermediary between internal Git commit form and work-tree form, and most repositories have a work-tree, which lets you get at the commits' files *as* files.

## What `git checkout` does

The `git checkout` command mainly copies commits into the index and work-tree, so that you can move around throughout the history of all commits and see the corresponding snapshot in your work-tree.  It also adjusts what Git calls `HEAD`.

The name `HEAD`, in Git, *always refers to the current commit* by its ID—but it does so in one of two different ways.  You can be "on a branch", in which case the name `HEAD` simply contains the name of the branch.  It's then the branch name that gets Git the ID of the current commit.  Or, you can have a "detached HEAD", in which case the name `HEAD` records the ID of the current commit.

If you give `git checkout` a branch name—such as `git checkout master`—it puts you "on the branch": it checks out the tip commit, since that's the ID stored in the branch name, and it puts the branch name in `HEAD`.  If you give `git checkout` a raw commit ID, or a tag name, or a remote-tracking branch name, it finds the corresponding ID, checks out that commit, and puts the ID into `HEAD`.

## What `git fetch`—and `git push`—do

All of the above steps work entirely with your own repository.  Git doesn't restrict you to just one repository, though.  At well-defined times that *you* choose, you can tell your Git to call up another Git, usually over the Internet, and have a sort of conversation with that other Git.

This is what both `git fetch` and `git push` do.  They call up some other Git, at the other end of some URL.  The URL is usually stored under a name, which is called a *remote*.  The most common one—often the only remote in any given repository—is `origin` (because `git clone` sets that one up for you).

Remember, though, Git mostly cares about *commits*.  So when your Git calls up another Git, the conversation they have is mostly about commits.  They do, of course, need a way to find the IDs of those commits, and for that they usually start with some branch names.  This is in general how Git starts everything: take a branch name, or maybe just the name `HEAD`, and find a commit ID.  Use that commit.  Then, if it's appropriate, go to that commit's parent and do something with *that* commit, and so on.

The `fetch` process in particular gets a list of all the branches in the other Git.  It then obtains all the *commits* that are in those branches that it does not already have in its own repository.  Those commits come with any necessary snapshot-files, almost as a sort of side effect.  Last, your Git takes their Git's branch names and *renames* them, turning those branch names into your own *remote-tracking branch* names.

If the remote is named `origin`, their (origin's) master becomes your `origin/master`.  You get all their commits, except for the ones you already have.  The ones you already have, you already have.  Your Git can be sure you have them because you have the IDs.  The ID of each commit is unique to that commit, and the commit is permanent and unchanging—so if you have the *same* ID they do, you both necessarily have the same *commit*.

Your Git and their Git use `git push` very similarly, but in the other direction, and with a twist: your Git gives them your commits—the ones you have that they don't, that is—and then asks them to set *their* `master`, or whatever branch you are pushing, to set as its tip commit, the same commit you have as the tip of *your* `master`.  There's no renaming here: you ask them to make their `master` exactly the same as your `master`.

When you `git fetch`, your Git *renames* their branch-names, so it's safe to just take them whole.  No matter what they did to *their* branches, this *cannot* affect your own branch names.  But when you `git push`, you have your Git ask them to *set* their branch-names, with no renaming at all.  If they don't like the requested setting, they can say "no, I won't set that": they can reject your push.  That doesn't happen with fetch, and that's where your initial question comes in.

## `git pull` = `git fetch` + something else

Fetching just gets you their new commits.  *Because* `git fetch` never touches your own branches, you often want a second step.

The main problem here is that the *correct* second step to take depends on what commits you brought in, and what commits you already had.  There are two main options: `git merge`, and `git rebase`.  You can program Git to make `git pull` do either one.  The default is to do `git merge`.

Again, the "right" command depends on what you have in your branches, what you got from the remote when you fetched, and how you want to work.  Most people, in practice, mostly want `git rebase` here, but `git pull` defaults to running `git merge`.  In many cases, both commands wind up doing the same thing, so that it doesn't matter that the default is the *wrong* command.  But I advise newbies to avoid `git pull`, because it does default to the command most people mostly *don't* want, and because when things go wrong—they always do eventually—the way to *recover* from the problem depends on you knowing that you ran `git rebase` or `git merge`.  If you actually use those directly, you will know.

Answer (score 2):

Use "git pull  --rebase" to synchronize your changes to local from remote.

Here is answer for git fetch
git fetch really only downloads new data from a remote repository - but it doesn't integrate any of this new data into your working files. Fetch is great for getting a fresh view on all the things that happened in a remote repository.

Git checkout , used to switch across branches of a repository.
Just google and you will get plenty of information:.

Comment: **but it doesn't integrate any of this new data into your working files**
Then i am okey with those three changes in existing files. But GIT FETCH should give a newly created file on local. shan't it ?

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) simply fetches the changes from the remote to your local machine. It doesn't apply them.

`git checkout MY_REMOTE/master` applies the fetched changes to your local copy of the files. **Warning**: If your local files have been modified (and not commited) your local changes will be lost when you type `git checkout MY_REMOTE/master`.

To apply both the remote and local changes

- Commit your local changes: `git commit -a -m "my commit"`
- Apply the remote changes: `git pull origin master`

This will merge the two change sets (local and remote)

Alternatively, you can use `pull --rebase origin master` to first apply your local commits, *then* apply the remote commits.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38361930/1370722)

Comment: **GIT FETCH  : You download changes to your local branch from origin through fetch. Fetch asks the remote repo for all commits that others have made but you don't have on your local repo. Fetch downloads these commits and adds them to the local repository.**

This is the exact thing that i am asking . If i have added a new file on remote repo, why it's not showing on my local repo when i do GIT FETCH MY_REMOTE master"

Comment: Better to say that `git fetch` obtains *commits*, rather than *changes*. Git stores snapshots, not changesets. (The difference is somewhat technical and only *sometimes* important, but when it is important, it can become *very* important, so best to start out with the right idea.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add all files and commit.
`git add . && git commit -m "<your_message>"`

also check any setting at coc-setting.json